# delegate method call

Tags: methods, delegates, using

I want to know simply what is the benefit of adding methods using += in delegates..

Comment: So that multiple delegate methods can be invoked in response to an event, I would imagine.

Comment: example : http://www.akadia.com/services/dotnet_delegates_and_events.html

Answer (score 0):

If you assigned a method to a delegate using =, you would replace any other methods that have already been assigned to that delegate.  By using +=, you are adding a new method without removing any existing methods already assigned.